# Why is there `gevent.queue.Queue` if `queue.Queue` already exists and is thread-safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, queue, gevent

There is this question [Why do we need gevent.queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737920/why-do-we-need-gevent-queue) which asks about the necessity of `gevent.queue.Queue` regarding the fact that there is no parallelism, but only concurrency with `gevent`. Rightfully, the answer explains:

> [...] you might want to ensure that a series of statements execute atomically [...]

So each method should be atomic, which explains why we need a queue object instead of a "regular" list, for example. However, according to Python docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html a `queue.Queue` object already has those safety features:

> It is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be exchanged safely between multiple threads. The Queue class in this module implements all the required locking semantics.

So why is there `gevent.queue.Queue` when `queue.Queue` already exists? Are more safety features required or is it a question of performance?

Comment: look at the source code for both and compare? you'll see that the `gevent.queue.Queue` does a lot more than that stdlib one

Comment: well for starters if you're exploring both of these queues try them out in your code and see if one suits your needs better than the other. besides a quick google search yields plenty of results like this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737920/why-do-we-need-gevent-queue which links to this --> https://blog.hownowstephen.com/post/46872742800/gevent-queue-intro

Comment: great, so read those posts, and come back when you have a more concrete question to ask, as opposed to something a little more opinion based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an answer to this question in [this comment](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1443#issuecomment-531240161) in one of the GitHub issues:

> gevent's Queue is directly implemented in terms of gevent primitives, rather than going through the abstraction of the monkey-patched `threading` libraries like the standard library Queue must do, and gevent's Queue can take advantage of the fact that certain operations cannot be interrupted by other greenlets. This lets it have reduced overhead and better performance.
>
> gevent's Queue is compatible with gevent and greenlets even if monkey-patching isn't used, whereas the standard library Queue isn't and requires monkey-patching. Not everyone like to monkey-patch.
>
> gevent's Queue also has a slightly richer interface, for example it can be iterated.